# Matching CSV Headers to MySQL Schema Columns

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, csv, database-design

I am working with a lot of CSVs hosted in an AWS S3 bucket, with many different schemata (e.g., one CSV might have headers ['Name', 'Height', 'Weight'] and one might have headers ['Name', 'DOB', 'Sex']).

I have an AWS RDS Aurora MySQL Serverless database instance, on it a database table with an encompassing schema (e.g., using the above example its schema might be ['Name', 'Height', 'Weight', 'DOB', 'Sex']).

I have written an AWS Lambda Python function that connects to the database, gets the schema of the relevant table as a list, connects to a given CSV from S3, gets its headers as a list, and compares them, throwing an exception if the CSV headers are not a subset of the database schema. I am trying now to write the code for the case that the CSV headers are a subset of the database schema, in which case the CSV can safely be loaded into the database.

Is there a tool to load the CSV such that its headers will be automatically matched to the corresponding columns in the database and rows populated accordingly? For example (although this seems like an unnecessarily resource-consuming workaround), if I were to load the CSV into a pandas DataFrame and then try to load that into the database, would column names automatically be matched? If so, how would that look in the code below?

```
...
if not set(cols).issubset(schema):
        raise Exception('CSV columns are not subset of schema (see above). Please reconfigure schema or column names and retry.')
    else:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            * CODE TO LOAD CSV TO DB WITH AUTOMATIC COLUMN-TO-SCHEMA MATCHING *
            conn.commit()
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the names to match up?  When they match, you want one row from each csv to create a total of only one row in the table?

Then it would be better to

1. LOAD DATA from one csv into one table (after doing `CREATE TABLE` and spelling out suitable params on the LOAD DATA)
2. LOAD DATA from the other csv into another table (... ditto ...)
3. INSERT INTO the final table a JOIN of those two tables.  (`INSERT INTO .. (...) SELECT ... JOIN ...`)

If there could be rows missing (for a name) from either of the rows, then you need a `FULL OUTER JOIN`.  MySQL does not have such, but it can be simulated.  Or step 3 could be done in more than one step.

Comment: This still requires that you specify CSV to schema mappings explicitly when you LOAD DATA no?

Comment: @OJT - I added some clues in that vein.

Comment: Thanks! It still looks like you'd have to spell out suitable parameters on LOAD DATA, which wouldn't be feasible in our use case (hence my searching for alternatives).

Comment: Oh.  What I am describing _assumes_ you know what is in each csv file.

Comment: Yes unfortunately this post was created after considering that a LOAD DATA solution would not be feasible. Thanks anyway though!

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up, I wound up using the Pandas method to_sql() on a DataFrame, which automatically matches column names.